# panorama background shrunk

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have a panorama view and would like, once i reached the end of my view, to be able to continue to the front (having my background image with matching ends) so that it looks like it is continuous, but when i go from front to end or vice-versa, as i slowly scroll left/right i can see the other end of my picture compressed(and once i get to that panoramaItem, it is decompressed looking natural).

My background is 1024/800 so it is ok by microsoft and my panormala code is :

```
<controls:Panorama>
            <controls:Panorama.Background>
                <ImageBrush  ImageSource="/_Assets/Layout/pasta-bg-3.jpg"/>
            </controls:Panorama.Background>

            <!--Panorama item one-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="a" Orientation="Horizontal">
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="a" Orientation="Horizontal">
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="a" Orientation="Horizontal">
            </controls:PanoramaItem>


</controls:Panorama>
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to adjust the size of your panorama background image depending on the number (and width) of panorama items youre using to achieve this effect.

Comment: is there a rule about this? or is it arbitrary?

Comment: This is based on my observations. Particularly with apps which use a small number of items but a very wide image and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I guess proper values for the `Width` property of the panorama Items , solves your problem.